# Create new column within a loop based on ifelse statement in R.

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, calculated-columns

I am not getting the expected results when I attempt to create a new column based upon an ifelse statement placed within a loop. The data in the new column is only based on some of the columns that are in the loop and not all of them. Why is this and how can I make the data in the new column be based on all the information in the loop? Here is a reproducible example of my attempt, in reality my dataframe contains over 500 columns:

```
 x1 <- sample( LETTERS[1:4], 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.65, 0.05) )
 x2 <- sample( LETTERS[1:4], 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.65, 0.05) )
 x3 <- sample( LETTERS[1:4], 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.65, 0.05) )
 x4 <- sample( LETTERS[1:4], 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.65, 0.05) )
 x5 <- sample( LETTERS[1:4], 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.65, 0.05) )
 x6 <- sample( LETTERS[1:4], 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.65, 0.05) )
 x7 <- sample( LETTERS[1:4], 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.65, 0.05) )
 x8 <- sample( LETTERS[1:4], 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.65, 0.05) )
 df <- data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4, x5,x6,x7,x8,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

 for (i in 2:7){
   df$newvar <- ifelse(df[,i] == "B" ,1,0)
 }
```

Comment: You don't need a loop.  How about `df$newvar <- as.numeric(apply(df, 1, function(x) any(x=="B")))`.  Your loop, by the way, overwrites `newvar` each time, so you only get the value for i=7.

Comment: Great that works! But if possible, I would like to know how to  do it within the loop, just to understand where it went wrong .

Comment: so, you want when **all** the elements of the `i` column of the `df` are equal to "B", to get a **vector** of ones ?

Comment: yes exactly, that would be great to understand how to do it in within a loop.

Comment: To do it within the loop as you have it, you need to 'carry forward' any 1s that you already have from previous i.  So perhaps `df$newvar <-
 pmax(df$newvar, ifelse(df[,i] == "B" , 1, 0)` - you will need to set `df$newvar <- 0` before the loop.

Comment: your loop is equivalent to `df$newvar <- ifelse(df[,7]=="B",1,0)`

Comment: @quant yes that's the plan

Comment: @AndrewGustar Thank you for the solution!